# Floating Vue dropdowns appearing outside container

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm currently using Floating Vue to handle my Dropdowns in Nuxt 2. Though, I have installed it via `npm` and added a plugin file to my `/plugins` folder, I've also added it to my `nuxt.config.js` file.

The dropdowns are working, though they look like they are attaching themselves to the `body` tag, resulting in them appearing at the bottom of the page outside of the `_nuxt` layout tag.

Has anyone used this Package with Nuxt2?

**FloatingVue.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import FloatingVue from 'floating-vue'

Vue.use(FloatingVue)
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/floaty' }
  ],
```

**Template**

```
      <VDropdown
        :distance="6"
      >
        <!-- This will be the popover reference (for the events and position) -->
        <button>Click me</button>

        <!-- This will be the content of the popover -->
        <template #popper>
            Hello
        </template>
      </VDropdown>
```

Comment: You a proper popover library, e.g. [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/)

Comment: @IVOGELOV it's a library made by Akryum so it's not like it's some random guy. Totally okay IMO.

Comment: Hm, you should not really load that as a plugin because it will impact your global performance. Load it locally. Also, I'm not sure if it's something specific to this package but you may solve that with a few lines of CSS. Like a `position: relative` or alike. If the functionality works, then the job of the package is done pretty much. Otherwise, look a bit more into the documentation/examples/github issues.

Comment: Apologies, I was not aware that Popper.JS is now Floating UI. Akryum of course is a serious and stable name in the community. You can specify the container (where the dropdown will be attached) either through the [global config](https://floating-vue.starpad.dev/guide/config.html) or as a per-component prop.